# Are UK entry stamps considered visas?

Tags: visas, uk

I am in the process of applying for a UK work visa. The visa application asks me to list all the visas issued to me by the UK in the last 10 years. I have traveled to the UK as a tourist in the last 10 years, but as a US citizen, I did not need to apply for a tourist visa, and instead I got my passport stamped upon entering the UK, like this:

[image]

Are these entry stamps considered visas? Do I need to list them in the visa application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An entry stamp means you've cleared immigration whereas a visa allows you to make a formal request to enter a country. I don't think an entry stamp counts as a visa, especially in the case of tourism because as a US citizen you don't need one anyway

Comment: Unless the stamp mentions that it is a visa as well, I am sure I have seen such a stamp just,can't remember where.

Comment: @MeNoTalk a visa on arrival kind of deal ?

Comment: No, an entry stamp with a note saying this is a visa for n days.

Comment: @MeNoTalk: This is the kind of stamp that is on my passport: http://www.rathburn.net/visa/uk/LHR%20Enter%20080403.jpg I hope this is not the specific type you are talking about.

Comment: @Alex No, that's just a normal entry stamp, not a visa-on-arrival. Such a stamp will explicitly state that it is a visa.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a visa if you go further to the aplication you will see another question asking you if have visited the uk before