# How Soon Can I Visit the UK From US?

Tags: uk, international-travel, us-citizens, visa-free-entry, repeat-visits

I am a US citizen. In August 2021 I went to England for the first time to visit my now fiancé. I stayed for 5 and a half months before returning to the US. We cannot afford a fiancé/spousal visa, so I am planning to apply for a standard or travel visa (in the future I do plan on getting one so one day I can become a UK citizen). But I would like to know how soon I can travel back to the UK, as Id like to come back as soon as possible. I'm not sure if there are any limits to how long I have to wait to come back and stay for another 6 months.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before, some info here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96633/how-soon-can-i-re-enter-the-uk

Answer (score 5):

The Immigration Rules ‘Eligibility Requirements for Visitors’ state:

V 4.2. The applicant must satisfy the decision maker that they are a genuine visitor, which means the applicant:

(a) will leave the UK at the end of their visit; and

(b) will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home; and

(c) is genuinely seeking entry or stay for a purpose that is permitted under the Visitor route as set out in Appendix Visitor: Permitted Activities and at V 13.3; and

(d) will not undertake any of the prohibited activities set out in V 4.4. to V 4.6; and

(e) must have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation to their visit without working or accessing public funds, including the cost of the return or onward journey, any costs relating to their dependants, and the cost of planned activities such as private medical treatment. The applicant must show that any funds they rely upon are held in a financial institution permitted under FIN 2.1 in Appendix Finance.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor

There is no fixed rule underpinning V4.2(b). Typically it is interpreted to mean a visitor making repeat visits should spend *at least* the same amount of time *out* of the UK as *in* it. In your case, that would mean at least 6 months from the date you left.

Keep in mind that repeated visits for almost 6 months is not a typical visitor pattern. It might be a red flag under V4.2(a) causing a Border Official to ask how someone is able to leave their country of residence for such long periods and whether they are a genuine visitor. Ideally you should bring documents to prove ties to home to show at the UK border, if asked.

Finally, US citizens do not need a visa to enter the UK as a visitor for up to 6 months https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y so there is no need for you to apply for one.

Comment: If I apply for any sort of visa and present it to a border official such as a work or fiancé visa, will it raise fewer red flags? I genuinely just want to see my fiancé again

Comment: Which work visa are you eligible for https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/work-visas? Ditto fiancée visa? Obviously less red flags if you have a visa but there are quite a few hoops to jump through to get one. What ties to the US do you have? When did your fiancé last visit you there? Long distance relationships usually look better if there are reciprocal visits, not just one way. Have him visit you instead?